# Read adjacency matrix from file - Competitive programming

Tags: c, performance, gcc

I have to do an assignment where I have to read a file that contains an adjacency matrix and later do some stuff.
I have all working but my code is very slow, at least for the benchmarking system.

I'm reading all the file rows in this code snippet below:

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
    parse(buf);
    i++;
}
```

and then I initialize my 2d array with all the values using strtok and atoi:

```
void parse(char *str, int count, char *sep) {
    //char *aux = malloc(count * sizeof(char*));
    char *aux;
    aux = strtok(str, sep);

    int j = 0;

    while (aux) {
         array[(i*DIM) + j] = atoi(aux);
         j++;
         aux = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }
    //free(aux);
}
```

Arrays are DIM*DIM size and each INT is separated by a comma.

Sample input for a 3*3 matrix:

```
1,20,1
0,111,3
4,7,10
```

How can I improve this for better performances?

EDIT:

array definition:

```
array = malloc(DIM*DIM*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: How is `array` declared and what's the reason you are not using a 2D array? Also why do you allocate room for multiple `aux` when you are just using one?

Comment: Anyway I think the solution you are looking for is `strtol` called repeatedly in a loop. No need for strtok and malloc. And atoi should never be used.

Comment: When posting comments, check the little Help link bottom right corner of the box for formatting tips. Anyway, you should add clarification to the question itself with an edit.

Comment: I was oriented on using strtol, is this a lot faster than atoi and strtok?

Comment: _Side note:_ Using `malloc` and `free` is actually a memory leak. The value from `malloc` is trashed by `aux = strtok(...)`; And, _that_ value can _not_ be passed to `free` because it is _not_ in the heap in an aligned spot. This is not detected because the final value will be `NULL` So, just remove both calls.

Comment: `but my code is very slow` How do you know that reading from file is the cause?

Comment: I'm using Valgrind and Callgrind to debug the code and the time took from the strtok and atoi instructions is huge.

Comment: @sarcokiller The main advantage of strtol over atoi is that it has error handling, so you can check its result in a loop. Dynamic memory allocation is slow and using strtok + some other parsing function at the same time loops over the same data multiple times. I can cook up an answer with some example code.

Comment: @Lundin I would appreciate an example with strtol if you have time :)

Answer (score 1):

The `malloc` part makes no sense since you just need one single character pointer for `strtok`. Similarly, functions like `strtol` or `atoi` already parse the data, so you don't even need `strtok` - it just takes up extra time in this case. Furthermore, `atoi` doesn't have any error handling so it should never be used.

So you can just call `strtol` in a loop and it will do what you want. By checking the `endptr` argument you can see if each read was successful or not (`man strtol`). And then next lap in the loop, start over from `endptr + 1`.

If combining this with your 2D int array requirement, the function might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void csv_to_int (size_t col, size_t row, int dst[col][row], const char* str)
{
  const char* ptr = str;
  char* end;

  for(size_t c=0; c<col; c++)
  {
    for(size_t r=0; r<row; r++)
    {
      int val=strtol(ptr,&end,10);
      if(ptr==end)
      {
        return ;
      }
      dst[c][r]=val;
      ptr = end+1;
    }
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  const char* input = "1,20,1\n0,111,3\n4,7,10\n";
  int arr[3][3];
  
  csv_to_int(3, 3, arr, input);

  for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
      printf("%3d ", arr[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
 1  20   1
 0 111   3
 4   7  10
```

This is of course assuming that the input suits the 3x3 format - this code has almost no error handling.

Comment: For a fast check I implemented half of your solution and the code is running already 2 times faster! I'm basically only using this instead of strtok and atoi but I'm still parsing line by line the file with fgets!
I will update you soon!

Comment: @sarcokiller Notably the file handling will be the bottleneck in your code, so if you can read the file all in one go with fread etc, that will be the most important optimization you can do.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I improve this for better performances?

So do not use these functions, if you think they are slow. Limit your requirements - do not handle locale specific digits. So read and convert it yourself. Blatantly disregard error checking. Something along:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char data[] ="1,20,1\n0,111,3\n4,7,10\n";
    FILE *f = fmemopen(data, sizeof(data), "r");
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    #define DIM 3
    int array[20];

    // this reading part
    int buf = 0;
    for (int c; (c = fgetc(f)) != EOF; ) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            array[i * DIM + j] = buf;
            buf = 0;
            ++i;
            j = 0;
        } else if (c == ',') {
            array[i * DIM + j] = buf;
            buf = 0;
            ++j;
        } else {
            buf *= 10;
            buf += (c - '0');
        }
    }
    array[i * DIM + j] = buf;
    ++j;

    // checking
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            printf("%d %d = %d\n", i, j, array[i * DIM + j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Even further, ignore portability, and use system calls (on unix - `read(STDIN_FILENO)`) instead of C API.

Comment: This is bad advice in my opinion; reading character by character is slow due to function call overhead. Using `read()` is also not a magic wand that makes things faster. Granted, OP's question is also lacking enough detail so it's hard to give a good answer. Ideally, you would be able to benchmark OP's code against your solution.

Comment: @G.Sliepen *Using read() is also not a magic wand that makes things faster.*  It's a great first-order approximation of one, though, if only because it avoids reading more characters than needed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm not sure I see what you mean with avoiding reading more characters than needed? The only thing I can imagine is that it avoids unnecessary copies; with `fgets()` it might do a `read()` behind the scenes into a large-ish buffer, and then copy into the buffer provided by the caller. But if you are reading the whole file anyway, you will have read the same amount with `fgets()` as with manual calls to `read()`. My point is that going low-level without even knowing if `fgets()` is the issue here is not good advice.

Comment: `This is bad advice in my opinion; reading character by character is slow due to function call overhead` the question is `How can I improve this for better performances?`. Original code used `fgets`. Is my proposed version not improved for better performance?

Comment: @KamilCuk The only thing we know is that according to the OP, `strtok()` and `atoi` took a long time. So I would just show how to implement those yourself, and keep the file I/O as it is.

Comment: @G.Sliepen You are wrong. Character-based input is the fastest possible solution. (stdio is buffered) Using `getc()` instead of `fgetc()` will even avoid the function-call overhead.

Comment: @wildplasser  `getc()` may be slow due to synchronization. Try `getc_unlocked` and see how it shines

Comment: @wildplasser I see Clang and GCC emitting regular function calls to `getc()`. However, `getc_unlocked()` as @tstanist mentioned does get inlined.